# Laravel 4 Blade - Fill table dynamically

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have three arrays that will form a schedule. The top row of the table contains letters, the first column contains numbers and the rest of the table will contain the data in the third array. I have managed to fill the top row and first column successfully.
The problem is the arrays are filled dynamically so how can I make sure the data is placed in the correct cell in an efficient way?!

```
A1 = {a,b,c}
A2 = {1,2,3}
A3 = {(a,1), (c,2), (b,2), (a,3), (c,1)}

   | a | b | c
----------------
 1 |   |   |  

 2 |   |   |

 3 |   |   |
```

Any ideas?!

**Update**

Expected Output:

```
   | a     | b     | c
----------------------
 1 |  A3-1 |       | A3-5  

 2 |       |  A3-3 | A3-2

 3 |  A3-4 |       |
```

Comment: What should the output look like given the data above?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I updated my question with the expected output.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Cant you format it to be easier to use?

Comment: It's fetched form the database coming from the controller in the form of arrays.

Comment: @omarsafwany And what do those arrays look like?

Comment: @lukasgeiter what do you mean?! The format stated above is how the array looks like.

Comment: @omarsafwany Not really. Where is the value that should be displayed? I only see the "coordinates".

Comment: @lukasgeiter Ah, I got your point. Each one in the A3 contains the id of both the A1 and A2. I need to check the cells to see if the current A1 id matches the one in the current A3 and the current A2 id matches the one in A3, a name would be placed in the current cell.